# Dirty ways to create Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have recently started digging into Multi-Threading in Java. While exploring things, I discovered there are 2 quick and dirty ways to create Threads "on the go" in Java. Here is the example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread: "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }.start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread: "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("hello");
        }

    }).start();
}
```

1. First one is the one which starts with `new Thread() {`
2. Second one comes after that which starts with `new Thread(new Runnable() {`

I just wanted to ask if both of the ways are correct? Any difference other than difference of Implementing **Runnable Interface** v/s Extending **Thread class**?

Comment: What notion of "dirty" are you referring to?

Comment: @ChrisMartin "dirty" as in the Thread is not associated with any class. Should I rephrase to "inline"?

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is "anonymous".

Comment: Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both ways are acceptable (and neither way is "dirty" in my opinion). The first is less verbose and the one I would prefer in a trivial case like this. If you're extending Thread, so you can also skip `Thread.currentThread()`:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread: " + getName());
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}.start();
```

In any non-trivial case however (i.e. if the thread does more than just a couple of prints) the usual rule of ["favor composition over inheritance"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) applies which advocates the second approach.

If you're using Java 8, you can even take advantage of the fact that `Runnable` is a functional interface:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    System.out.println("hello");
}).start()
```

A final note: I rarely use threads these days. Whenever I do, I tend to end up rewriting it using ExecutorServices.

Comment: what do you mean by _less verbose_?

Comment: The first one has been officially discouraged, the reason being exposure to all the `Thread` class's internals which possibly leads to unexpected and unintuitive involvement of lesser-known Java naming resolution rules against members which the programmer isn't even aware of. The general principle behind this is *Favor composition over inheritance*.

Comment: @Anurag, by less verbose I mean less code (since you leave out the `new Runnable()` part). @MarkoTopolnik has a good point regarding composition though. Reformulating my answer slightly.